# .net wpf pass data between pages

Tags: .net, wpf

I need to pass parameter between page but Programmatic Navigation with a Pack URI (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/navigation-overview#programmatic-navigation-with-a-pack-uri)

**Note:** I don't want to use the constructor to pass the parameter

Currently I do this:

```
 Uri uri = new Uri("AnotherPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(uri, parameter);
```

but once again microsoft forgot to put an example on how to receive the data in the other page.

I try this in the second page to receive the parameter:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.LoadCompleted += NavigationService_LoadCompleted;
    }

    private void NavigationService_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

but it's not working.

In this post ([How to pass values (parameters) between XAML pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444816/how-to-pass-values-parameters-between-xaml-pages))  in the second point use

example:
2. Using NavigationEventArgs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // NavigationEventArgs returns destination page
    Page destinationPage = e.Content as Page;
    if (destinationPage != null) {

        // Change property of destination page
        destinationPage.PublicProperty = "String or object..";
    }
}
```

but **OnNavigatedFrom** doesn't exist

In this post use a global variable like([How to pass values between two pages in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902095/how-to-pass-values-between-two-pages-in-wpf))

```
string myText = (string)Application.Current.Properties["test"];
```

maybe this is the solution if there does not exist a better way

here ([Passing data between pages in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27734944/passing-data-between-pages-in-wpf)) no example

I don't know maybe I'm missing something about WPF Navigation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/navigation-overview) Can someone point me in the right direction or am I just wasting my time and this is impossible to do.

I'm sorry for my English, I don't speak

Comment: Won't it be easy if you setup a separate singleton class to store data from first page and on loading the second page lookup the data?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/structured-navigation-overview